# Ehcache Java Spring MVC and pagination @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, caching, pagination, ehcache

I use Ehcache 2.9.0 In my Spring Application and I would like to be able to cache a result based on the pagination.

First is how I use Ehcache right now:

```
@Cacheable(value ="EmployeesByCompanyId", key="#companyId")    
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByCompanyId(String companyId) throws Exception {
        return employeeRepository.getEmployeesByCompanyId(companyId);
}

@CacheEvict(value ="EmployeesByCompanyId", key="#company.id")
public Employee createNewEmployee(Employee employee, Company company)
{ ... }
```

Now is how I would like to use it for the same purpose but with a pagination. Example (not correct but it's the idea):

```
@Cacheable(value ="EmployeesByCompanyId", key="#companyId#page#maxResult"})    
@Override
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByCompanyId(String companyId, int page, int maxResult) throws Exception {
            return employeeRepository.getEmployeesByCompanyId(companyId, page, maxResult);
        }
```

Then when I had a new employee to the list it should Evict the cache but I would like to evict the cache related to a companyId. If I write something like that would it remove the cache related to the companyId:

```
@CacheEvict(value ="EmployeesByCompanyId", key="#companyId")
```

How should I do to make the caching work with the pagination and evict the cache related to the companyId when I add a new employee to this company?

Comment: Just specify `allEntries=true` for the `CacheEvict` that will clear the whole cache.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry my bad, I just would like to evict the cache related to the `companyId`. Not the entire cache `EmployeesByCompanyId`. Or would it be possible to cache all the employees related to a `companyId` and then request only a part of this employees cached for the pagination?

Comment: I get your point, I don't think you can do it with annotations. You should get your EhCache Manager bean and get all the keys starting with "companyid" and remove them.

Comment: @selvinsource Thank you. I'm trying to follow your advices so I declared my cacheManager:`@Autowired
 private CacheManager cacheManager;` then I get the right cache and with the key `Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("EmployeesByCompanyId"); cache.get("companyId");`  but then How do you think I can get all the keys related to this cache? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a possible solution based on our comments.

Get the native EhCache object (as the Cache interface from Spring doesn't support getKeys method) from the cache manager

```
@Autowired private CacheManager cacheManager;
...
EhCache cache = (EhCache) cacheManager.getCache("EmployeesByCompanyId").getNativeCache();
```

Then you can iterate the cache keys, get the ones starting with companyId and remove them from the cache

```
for (Object key: cache.getKeys()) {
  if((String)key.startsWith(companyId))
    cache.remove(key);
}
```

See http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.8.4/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html

Comment: Does the Class `EhCache` reference `net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCache` ? my IDE tells me that it's deprecated. What do you think?

Comment: net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache as the link I posted

Comment: Ok i got it @selvinsource thank you. The Class **Ehcache** is with a lowercase **c**. Here is what I wrote to solve the problem `Ehcache cache = (Ehcache) cacheManager.getCache("EmployeesByCompanyId").getNativeCache();
for (Object key: cache.getKeys()) {
 String keyCache = key.toString();
 if(keyCache.startsWith(companyId))
         cache.remove(key);
 }` It's working good.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked. As well as accepting the answer can you mark the answer as useful? Thanks!

Comment: yeah, you are right, I didn't check your reputation, it's fine, thanks anyway :)